# Getting numeric value to the left of a delimiter from a substring in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull the numeric value out of a substring of data from a column. I want to pull the numeric value from the left of GM. The problem is that the data is not uniform. Sometimes it shows up with a space between the number and GM, sometimes GM and the number are right next to eachother. I am using Microsoft SQL and cant run functions. I need to run it in a select statement.

```
Product x SOD 5GM 200ML
```

I want it to pull 5

```
RSAIZED2GMVL6/BX
```

I want it to pull 2

```
Product x2 30 MCG SOD 5.5GM 200ML
```

I want it to pull 5.5 MG.

Comment: You will need to provide more strict logic for this. You are looking for some combination of PATINDEX and  SUBSTRING, however with the logic you provided doesn't account for spaces or decimals. How 5 5.5 MG would be treated (5.5, 5 5.5, 55.5)?

Comment: 5 5.5 MG would be treated as 5.5

Comment: You'll need to provide definitions of the logic applied. That was just an example. Anything you do not explicitly define will be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will perform the logic you asked for. If you find any exceptions, additional tuning will be required.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(string,CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string)
        END,CHARINDEX('GM', string)- CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string)
        END)
FROM @tbl
WHERE   --Exclude records that do not have a positive length for the substring.
    CHARINDEX('GM', string)- CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9]GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]_GM%', string)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]GM%', string)
        END > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error message though. It shows results and then errors out. Do you know what this is?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 132
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: That means that the length you are passing the substring (the CHARINDEX - CASE statement) is giving you a negative or NULL value. This would happen if there were strings without GM in them. You can bypass this by including an additional where clause (answer edited) however that will exclude these rows, not resolve the issue. You can identify them by selecting the string column where the CHARINDEX - CASE statement IS NULL.